# Javascript Google map api not responding on my web app when viewing it from mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, mobile

Below there is my code for creating the google maps, they work fine when i view them from my desktop but when i resize my browser or use my mobile phone  i cant zoom, click on events or anything on maps, they are acting like images in that case.I dont know what might be the problem. I tried touchstart on click event but nothing changed. Any ideas?

```
  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12" id="map" style="width:100%;height:600px;"></div>

  function mymodal(thismodal){
      $(thismodal).modal('show');
    }
          function initMap() {
            var myLatLng = {lat: 40.69951725159461, lng: 24.64619453476564};


           var locations = [
          ['Skala Rachoniou',40.782232, 24.614488, 1],
          ['Ormos Prinou', 40.7584839,24.5613919  , 2],
          ['Skala Kallirachis', 40.7067027,24.5288304, 3],
          ['limenaria', 40.627805,24.568963, 4],
          ['Pefkari', 40.61778,24.5892925, 5],
          ['Potos', 40.6108026,24.606527, 6],
          ['Giola', 40.5944829,24.6648514, 7],
          ['Moni Archaggelou', 40.5971617,24.6994095, 8] ,
          ['Thymonia Beach', 40.602884,24.7176294, 9],
          ['Aliki', 40.605479,24.7394179, 10],
          ['Agios Ioannis Beach', 40.6180698,24.7612051, 11],
          ['Makriammos Theologou', 40.6548492,24.7565726, 12],
          ['Loutra', 40.654139,24.7553921, 13],
          ['Kinira', 40.6649342,24.760148, 14],
          ['Chrisi Akti', 40.7103487,24.7519925, 15],
          ['Chrisi Ammoudia', 40.7314367,24.7576794, 16],
          ];
          var marker = [];



            var image='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pan-tera/flags/32/Greece-Flag-icon.png';
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 5,
              center: myLatLng
            });

            var map1 =new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('zoomed'), {
              zoom: 11,
              center: myLatLng
            });

            for ( var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map1,
            icon:image,


          });
    var selector = "#myModal"+   i;


     }  google.maps.event.addListener(marker[0], 'click', function() {
        $("#myModal0").modal('show');
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[1], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal1").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[2], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal2").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[3], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal3").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[4], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal4").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[5], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal5").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[6], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal6").modal('show');
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[7], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal7").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[8], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal8").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[9], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal9").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[10], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal10").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[11], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal11").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[12], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal12").modal('show');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[13], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal13").modal('show');
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[14], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal14").modal('show');
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[15], 'click', function() {
         $("#myModal15").modal('show');
    });


            var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatLng,
              map: map,
              title: 'Zoomed map'
            });


          }
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't another HTML element on top of the map div? It could be something invisible to the eye.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am not sure what you are asking here, or  how you expect us to solve it You might read https://stackoverflow.com/help-how-to-ask for some guidance on how to help us to help you